# $.ajax in JQuery call same VM

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Code in index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function carregaPagina(item, pai, filho, url) {
                var caminho = item != null ? $(item).attr('data-click') : url;
                if (item != null) {
                    if ($(item).attr('data-json') != null) {
                        $('#' + $(item).attr('local-json')).html($(item).attr('data-json'));
                    }
                }
                if (pai != "" && pai != null) {
                    $('#' + pai).slideToggle(1000);
                }
                $.ajax({
                    url: caminho,
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#' + filho).slideToggle(0);
                        $('#' + filho).html(data);
                        $('#' + filho).slideToggle(1000, function () {
                            if (typeof completaLoad !== 'undefined' && $.isFunction(completaLoad)) {
                                completaLoad();
                            }

                            if ($('#' + pai).css('display') !== 'none') {
                                $('#' + pai).slideToggle(0);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(document).on('click', '.grid', function (e) {
                    if (e.handled !== true) {
                        carregaPagina(this, 'TelaConsulta', 'TelaEditar', null);
                        e.handled = true;
                    }
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            .grid, .item, .btnVoltar {
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            #TelaConsulta {
                background-color: #81BEF7;
            }
            #TelaEditar {
                background-color: #58FAAC;
            }
            #TelaItem {
                background-color: #F6D8CE;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="TelaConsulta">
            <ul>
                <li><span class="grid" data-click="editar.php?id=25">Edit</span></li>
                <li><span class="grid" data-click="editar.php?id=35">Edit</span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="TelaEditar">
        </div>
        <div id="TelaItem">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Code in editar.php:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on('click', '.item', function (e) {
                if (e.handled !== true) {
                    debugger;
                    var url = 'item.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>';
                    carregaPagina(null, 'TelaEditar', 'TelaItem', url);
                    e.handled = true;
                }
                return false;
            });
            $('#TelaEditar .btnVoltar').click(function () {
                $('#TelaEditar').slideToggle(1000, function () {
                    $('#TelaConsulta').slideToggle(1000);
                    $('#TelaEditar').empty();
                    $('#TelaEditar').removeAttr('style');
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
    Id: <?php
      echo $_GET['id'];
    ?><br><br>
    <span class="item">Item</span><br><br>
    <span class="btnVoltar">Voltar</span>
```

Code in item.php:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#TelaItem .btnVoltar').click(function () {
            $('#TelaItem').slideToggle(1000, function () {
                $('#TelaEditar').slideToggle(1000);
                $('#TelaItem').empty();
                $('#TelaItem').removeAttr('style');
            });
            return false;
        });
        debugger;
    });
</script>
Id: <?php echo $_GET['id']; ?><br><br>
<span class="btnVoltar">Voltar</span>
```

In the index.php file click on the 1st Edit.

Insert a debugger in Item button on editar.php note that when you click the button it opens the VM108 and return Id 25.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjWER.png

Insert a debugger in the load file item.php note that it opens the VM119 and return Id 25.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsljX.png

Soon after I click the back button on item.php file, and then the back button of editar.php.
In the index.php file click on the 2nd Edit and return Id 35.

When you click the Item button on editar.php note that it reopens the VM108.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSQfj.png

When it appears the item.php file note that it opens the VM141 and return Id 25.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rbwf.png

This is my doubt, every time I open the editar.php it always returns me the VM108.
When this occurs it is not being updated the item Id and generating the problem.

Link simulation: [link](http://microworks.com.br/cristiano/teste/)

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. could you provide a plunker or something ?

Comment: Look this example [link](http://microworks.com.br/cristiano/teste/)

Comment: So... why shouldn't it use the same compiled code when the uncompiled code is the same? Also, you say it's generating a problem, but not what the problem is. You probably shouldn't be depending on ajax-loaded documents to share state with the parent document. Each should be isolated from each other.

Comment: I changed my code to PHP now in my [link](http://microworks.com.br/cristiano/teste/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is occurring because the click event is still active.

How am carrying through Ajax HTML and JS code did not know to create a click event it would be active on the screen that I'm carrying the call using $(document).on(), to return to the home screen'm not removing the event you should use the calls $(document).off().

My editar.php file looked like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('click', '.item', function (e) {
            if (e.handled !== true) {
                debugger;
                var url = 'item.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>';
                carregaPagina(null, 'TelaEditar', 'TelaItem', url);
                e.handled = true;
            }
            return false;
        });
        $('#TelaEditar .btnVoltar').click(function () {
            $('#TelaEditar').slideToggle(1000, function () {
                //Remove click event
                $(document).off('click', '.item');
                $('#TelaConsulta').slideToggle(1000);
                $('#TelaEditar').empty();
                $('#TelaEditar').removeAttr('style');
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
Código: <?php
    echo $_GET['id'];
?><br><br>
<span class="item">Item</span><br><br>
<span class="btnVoltar">Voltar</span>
```

This is because I am passing the Id directly in JS, if perchance I seek the value in a form field for example, there would be no need to clean the event.